# Handling different formats in the same column

Tags: excel, format, type-conversion, vba

Run into a bit of an issue, a file that I receive contains a column that consists of numbers and text, currently the format of this column is in text format.  Is there a way to convert the numbers to number format and leave the text as text? I need to be able to do this for comparisons I do later in the code and due to this formatting it shows up as the numbers being different due to them being in text format.

Here is the code I am currently implementing to convert the imported version to text:

```
Columns("T:T").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("T1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Thanks for any help/advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler than VBA - go to the Data Ribbon, select the column, and click Text to Columns, then Finish.

This usually auto-detects the presence of numbers formatted as text, and reformats appropriately.